# How to do line breaks when mixing in Simplified Chinese characters and non-Chinese characters?

Tags: grammar, simplified-characters, syntax

**Context:**

I am working on a video game with a Simplified Chinese translation. I'm not handling the translation myself, but I am working on importing the translated strings into the game's engine.

I know that there are certain characters that cannot start or end a line in Simplified Chinese, as I have found on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_rules_in_East_Asian_languages#Simplified_Chinese). However, this page doesn't confirm or deny if this applies to non-Chinese characters mixed with Chinese characters in the same string.

**Question:**

One of the strings in the game renders like so:

[image]

The question I have is about the text below the black line:

[image]

> 被消除后能给予100枚<coin_icon>。

Is it gramatically correct for non-Chinese characters (in this case "100") to be broken up by a line break?

If this is gramatically correct, is it also okay for non-Chinese/non-digit characters to be broken up by a line break? For example:

> 添加到Steam愿望单！

Would a line break be okay between "St" and "eam" ?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not acceptable to break up 100 to 1 00 in any language

line break between 一百 is acceptable, but from a graphic designer's standpoint, it doesn't look professional

breaking up non-digit/non-Chinese characters. Such as "Steam" with a line break is also unacceptable